# How to fix 'may not respond to' for selector introduced in newer SDK?

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-lion

I have an application which builds against the 10.5 SDK. I still want it to behave correctly when running on 10.7 systems. The code snippet

```
if ([window respondsToSelector:@selector(setRestorable:)])
{
  [window setRestorable:NO];
}
```

however, triggers the compiler warning

```
'NSWindow' may not respond to '-setRestorable:'
```

because the setRestorable selector was introduced in the 10.7 SDK. What would be the proper way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility I found was this:

```
if ([window respondsToSelector:@selector(setRestorable:)])
{
  IMP setRestorableFunc =
    [window methodForSelector:@selector(setRestorable:)];

  setRestorableFunc(window, @selector(setRestorable:), NO);
}
```

Not sure whether this is the best option, though.

Answer (score 2):

Try to create a dummy (never used) protocol in some header and make sure it is imported in the source where you use it:

```
@protocol Compatibility
- (void)setRestorable:(BOOL)flag;
@end
```

I believe this should persuade the compiler that the class might implement the protocol (even when not explicitly specified in its header) and should stop complaining.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little how you would do this?

Comment: Just create a new header (e.g. compat.h) with the protocol as above, and import in your source file where you send the message. I.e. the compiler will know the protocol when compiling your code and it should assume that any used class may implement it so it should not warn.

Comment: OK, what's missing from your answer is that I need to cast the variable window to ``id`` for this to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply cast it to `id`:

```
if ([window respondsToSelector:@selector(setRestorable:)])
{
  [(id)window setRestorable:NO];
}
```

Comment: Without defining the protocol as @mity suggested, this still causes a warning in my setup.

Comment: @Tobias: Actually, come to think of it, I don't really understand why you're getting the warning in the first place. Aren't you building against the 10.7 SDK? If so, shouldn't `setRestorable:` already be in the headers?

Comment: No, like I wrote above, I'm building against the 10.5 SDK.

Comment: @Tobias: why don't you build against the 10.7 SDK and set the deployment target to 10.5 (or earlier)?

Comment: Good point, this is indeed one way to go forward mid term, but for reasons too complicated to elaborate here not possible in the short term.